# wp_query with post_id not working

Tags: wordpress

I want to retrieve the post using the post id.
But i found that its retrieving the post based on custom post type and not by post id. This is my code. Please give me some suggestions.

```
$args = array(
        'post_type' => 'landingpage',
        'post_id' => '4110',
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'meta_query' => array(
                                 'relation' => 'AND',
                                    array(
                                        'key'     => 'page_link',
                                        'value'   => 'http://5.heypayless/Landing%20Pages/dedicated-web-programmers/',
                                        'compare' => '='
                                  )
                            )    
    );
       $obituary_query = new WP_Query($args);
    while ($obituary_query->have_posts()) : $obituary_query->the_post();
        $test= get_field('price/hr_for_test_services');
        $junior=get_field('price/hr_for_junior');
        $senior=get_field('price/hr_for_senior');
        $lead=get_field('price/hr_for_lead_designer');
        $features=get_field('features_for_test_services');
        $features2=get_field('features_for_junior');
        $features3=get_field('features_for_senior');
        $features4=get_field('features_for_lead_designer');
    endwhile;
     echo $post->ID;
    wp_reset_postdata();

    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
        $args = array( 'p' => 42, // id of a page, post, or custom type 'post_type' => 'any');
        $my_posts = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: yeah but i want post to be retrieved based on post_id itself. but above code gives me all the posts having post_type=>'landingpage'.
Seems like post_id=>'4110' is not working at all.

Comment: Aha So try this 
$args = array(
'p' => 42, // id of a page, post, or custom type
'post_type' => 'any');
$my_posts = new WP_Query($args);

Comment: Greate !! Please mark it as answer, if this solved your problem :)

Answer (score 0):

[WP_Query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters) doesn't take a `post_id` argument. You need to use `page_id` instead. The type is an `int` not a `string`:

```
...

'page_id' => 4110,

...
```